# Generate WSO2 ESB Config Project with maven archetype

Tags: maven, wso2, maven-archetype, wso2-esb

I need to create an "ESB Config Project" (WSO2) and I want to use a maven archetype command.

What is ArchetypeGroupId and ArchytepeArtifactId for this type of project (ESB Config Project)?

I need to do it without using WSO2 Developer Studio.

I find nothing in the WSO2 website.

Comment: May i know why you want achieve that which is readily available?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an old WSO2 repository. (**dist.wso2.org/maven2**) and **archetype-catalog.xml** is malformed.

With the new repository works.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml
```